# When can we assuredly say that a function is little o of some other function?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I'm trying to determine a function $f(x)$ that is $O(f)$ but not $o(f)$ and also not $\Omega(f)$. Note the $f$ used in the asymptotic notation is not the same as $f(x)$.

Originally I thought of $f(x)=\log(x), O(x)$ but I am not convinced that $o(x)$ is invalid for this function.

Previously I thought it was, because I could always come up with some constant $c$ that would bring the function $x$ below $f(x)$. However, I could say the same for $o(2^x)$ because surely there is some infinitesimally small constant that I can find that will put $2^x$ below $f(x)$ at a given value $x$. Any advice in this matter?

Comment: Please finish improving the presentation of your question. All the
math should be done with LaTeX. Furthermore, you are using only two
function names and choose to call both `f`, whatever the font. This is
apparently not needed. Plese change your notation, as it is very
doubtful there is a good justification for it.

Comment: Is your question: find functions $f,g$ such that $f=O(g)$, $f \neq o(g)$, $f \neq \Omega(g)$?

Comment: If the question is what @YuvalFilmus says, we also have duplicates around.

Answer (score 2):

Your example doesn't work, since in fact $\log x = o(x)$. However, the function $\phi$ below is $O(x)$ but not $o(x)$ or $\Omega(x)$:
$$
\phi(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is even}, \\ 1 & \text{if $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is odd}. \end{cases}
$$